# I want to resample the columns in a group of 7 based on weeks starting sunday and ending saturday

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

```
Cid  2021-05-01| 2021-05-02 | 2021-05-03 | 2021-05-04| 2021-05-05|2021-05-06|2021-05-07|2021-05-08
120   25          30             40         10         15         20          5          5        
220   10          20             30         10         50         15          35         55
430   16          4              20         10         25         25          15         6
```

In the requirement Cid is the index and columns are of int64 datatype

I want to convert the columnNames to datetime and resample them in groups of 7 based(i.e) weeks, starting from sunday.

I tried converting the columnNames to dateTime format but unable to do so for past 2 day
Required Output

```
Cid  2021-05-01|2021-05-08
120   145        5        
220   170        55
430   115        6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `resample` to do 7 days aggregation.

```py
# Convert columns to DatetimeIndex if it is not yet
df = df.set_index('Cid')
df.columns = pd.to_datetime(df.columns)
```

Then, aggregate the sum over 7 days. "W-SAT" is weekly interval starting on Saturday. You want the date from the left side of the interval, so add label and closed options to left.

```py
df.resample('W-SAT', label='left', closed='left', axis=1).sum()
```

Result

```
     2021-05-01  2021-05-08
Cid
120         145           5
220         170          55
430         115           6
```

Comment: I guess instead of W-SAT it should be W-SUN as it indicates the start of week and not the end. I am still learning so I might be somewhat wrong though

Comment: You are right.  W-SAT is indicating week starting on SAT.  I just checked the date, 5/1 is Sat, your description and data is not matching.  The data you show is aggregating from Sat-Fri. If you want the aggregation from Sun-Sat, the data would change, but you could use "W-SUN"